# How to use tailwind inside an iFrame?

Tags: tailwind-css

How can I use tailwind within an iFrame during development?

Currently, when I add new styles, I'm creating a new css file with

```
npx tailwindcss build src/assets/css/tailwind.css -o dist/assets/css/index.css
```

and link this file in my iFrame, but this is a bit annoying.... is there a better way to do this during development?

Comment: did you figure out an answer to this?

Comment: sorry no, still do it that way for my design system ;(

Comment: did you found any answers to this??

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the tailwind cdn to the iframe.

**working demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-pascal-3y46c5

**automatically inject tailwind demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-goldwasser-5o50bx?file=/index.html

### demo code:

**`index.html:`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <script>
    function etw() {
      var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
      var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
      var tw = iframeDoc.createElement("script");
      tw.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.tailwindcss.com");
      tw.onload = function () {
        iframeDoc.body.innerHTML = iframeDoc.body.innerHTML; //re-render
      };
      iframeDoc.head.appendChild(tw);
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="/hello.html" title="IFrame"></iframe>
    <button onclick="etw()">click to enable tailwind in the iframe</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`hello.html:`**

```
<div class="bg-red-500 text-xl p-5 rounded-full">
  class="bg-red-500 text-xl p-5 rounded-full" div
</div>
```

### Second Demo index.html (Inject automatically):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <script>
    function etw() {
      var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
      var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
      var tw = iframeDoc.createElement("script");
      tw.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.tailwindcss.com");
      tw.onload = function () {
        iframeDoc.body.innerHTML = iframeDoc.body.innerHTML; //re render
      };
      iframeDoc.head.appendChild(tw);
    }
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", etw);
    });
  </script>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="/hello.html" title="IFrame"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

### **[NOTE:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn)**

> Use the Play CDN to try Tailwind right in the browser without any
> build step. The Play CDN is designed for development purposes only,
> and is not the best choice for production.

Comment: This is kinda of stupid question, but I can't get it to work. What if instead of clicking a button, tailwind styles should just work in the iframe on load? The obvious thing is to just include a script tag with src pointing to the tailwindcdn but.. I'm struggle with it not working on load... would you be able to provide another codesandbox by any chance?

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful! For anyone else in the future, I also realized mine wasn't working when putting in the cdn directly in the head because I was writing "className" instead of "class"... ugh!

Comment: the probability is very high that the colour tokens of Tailwind do not match the colours of the client... so this is not a real solution

Comment: @GregorVoinov  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn See part 2, `Try customizing your config`

Comment: anyway, note the cdn is very slow

Comment: ah ok, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know that, but as you already noted, not recommended for production.

Comment: For production, you should use tailwind on the iframe src